# What's the difference between beginAt and gotoPage in JWebUnit?

Tags: jwebunit

[`JWebUnit.beginAt`](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jwebunit/junit/JWebUnit.html#beginAt%28java.lang.String%29):

> Begin conversation at a URL absolute or relative to base URL. Use `getTestContext().setBaseUrl(String)` to define base URL. Absolute URL should start with "http://", "https://" or "www.".

[`JWebUnit.gotoPage`](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jwebunit/junit/JWebUnit.html#gotoPage%28java.lang.String%29):

> Go to the given page like if user has typed the URL manually in the browser. Use `getTestContext().setBaseUrl(String)` to define base URL. Absolute URL should start with "http://", "https://" or "www.".

So, one says "Begin conversation at URL absolute or relative to base URL", while the other says "Go to the given page like if user has typed the URL manually in the browser". This doesn't help me in the slightest in understanding them (well, specifically the former; the latter makes sense). What's the actual difference between them? Which should I be using, and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did manage to find the answer in the source code.

`beginAt` does two things: *start the browser*, then call `gotoPage` with its argument. Thus, you need to use `beginAt` the first time, and `gotoPage` subsequent times. (Perhaps if managing multiple windows it has more use; I haven't dug that deeply.)